# Arbitrary product of connected topological spaces is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

My teacher proved the following facts.

$\textbf{Lemma.}$ Let $\{0,1\}$ endowed with the discrete topology and consider $(X,\tau)$ a topological space. Then, $(X, \tau)$ is connected iff every continuous function $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ is constant.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ Let

$$\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$$

an arbitrary collection of topological spaces. If $X_i$ is connected for all $i\in I$, then

$$X=\prod_{i\in I} X_i$$

is a connected topological space (with the product topology).

${Proof.}$

If $X_i\ne \emptyset\quad  \forall i\in I$, let $\overline{x}=(\overline{x_i})_i\in X$. Then consider a continuous function $f:X\to \{0,1\}$. For the lemma, we have only to prove that $f$ is constant. Let

$$D=\{y=(\overline{y_i})_i\in X \quad | \quad y_i=\overline{x_i},\quad \mathrm{a.e.} \quad i\in I \}$$

So, the subset $D$ is a dense subset of $X$. In fact, if $U=\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ is an open set of the canonical basis of the product on $X$, then $U_i=X_i$ a.e. and so $U\cap D\ne \emptyset$. Because $D$ is dense, we need to prove that $f$ is constant only on $D$. Let show that $f(y)=f(\overline{x}), \quad \forall y\in D$. Inductively, it is enough to prove that $f(y)=f(\overline{x})$ for all $y=(y_i)_i\in X$ such that $y_i=\overline{x_i}$ for all $i\ne i_0$, with $i_0\in I$. Let we define:

$$ f_{\overline{x}}:X_{i_0}\to \{0,1\}, \quad x\mapsto f(y)$$

$f_{\overline{x}}$ is continuous, $y=(y_i)_i$ e $y_i=\begin{cases}\overline{x_i}, & i\ne i_0 \cr x_i, & i=i_0\end{cases}$.

Because $X_{i_0}$ is connected, $f_{\overline{x}}$ is constant and we've done.

I have two questions:

1. Why we can restrict $f$ to the dense subset $D$?
2. Defining $f_{\overline{x}}$ as done at the end, is that what is done inductively on each factor $X_i$?

Is there an easier way to show that the product of connected topological space is connected??

Comment: $f(\text{cl}(D))\subseteq \text{cl}f(D)$ so if $f$ is constant on $D$...